# Merge databases structure without loosing data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an application that has already been in production on a live server for a few months. Since then, the development of the application has advanced and I have added new fields to the database. What I want to do now is to be able to import the structure of the new database into the old one (the one in production on the live server) without losing it's data. Note that I work with a MySql database Phpmyadmin.
Can anyone help me and tell me how to handle this kind of situation please?
Thanks

The idea which come to me is to export the new database structure and import it on live server. Then export nly data from the old database and import it on the new database.

But doing so, there are problems especially when the new added fields are required as for the old database there were empty data.

Comment: Technically, adding new fields with default values does not have heavy overhead on the system. It's fast and safe.

Comment: @FatemehGharri I do not understand. Can you please explain ? Not only fields are added in the new db. There are also new tables

Comment: Do the new changes contain the data or just structure?

Comment: @FatemehGharri just the structure !

Comment: You need to have the create table / alter table statements for the database structure changes as a script and execute that script on the prod server.

Comment: So you can easily update your table using alter query. It runs for fewer than a second and it does not depend on the table records.